# T-SQL XML to Table

Tags: xml, t-sql, sql-server-2019

Good day everyone :)

here's my problem
I have a xml which looks like this

```
DECLARE @xml xml = 
    '<DT>
        <S>534</S>
        <NS>238</NS>
        <M>2</M>
        <NS>239</NS>
        <M>1</M>
        <NS>240</NS>
        <M>1</M>
    </DT>';
```

And this is the query I'm using

```
SELECT
    A.B.value('(.)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') AS S,
    C.D.value('(.)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') AS NS,
    E.F.value('(.)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') AS BN
FROM @xml.nodes('/DT') AS X(Y)
OUTER APPLY X.Y.nodes('S') AS A(B)
OUTER APPLY X.Y.nodes('NS') AS C(D)
OUTER APPLY X.Y.nodes('M') AS E(F);
```

I'm getting this result:

```
S    NS    M
534  238   2
534  238   1
534  238   1
534  239   2
534  239   1
534  239   1
534  240   2
534  240   1
534  240   1
```

But I would expect this one:

```
S    NS    M
534  238   2
534  239   1
534  240   1
```

What am I doing wrong and could you please help me with this?

Thanks a lot :)

**EDIT**

The xml has some more entries:

```
DECLARE @xml xml = 
'<DT>
    <S>534</S>
    <AB>2011</AB>
    <NS>238</NS>
    <M>2</M>
    <NS>239</NS>
    <M>1</M>
    <NS>240</NS>
    <M>1</M>
</DT>
<DT>
    <S>535</S>
    <AB>2000</AB>
    <NS>135</NS>
    <M>2</M>
    <NS>140</NS>
    <M>2</M>
</DT>
<DT>
    <S>536</S>
    <NS>005</NS>
    <M>2</M>
</DT>
<DT>
    <S>113</S>
    <AB>2006</AB>
    <NS>075</NS>
    <M>2</M>
    <NS>077</NS>
    <M>2</M>
    <NS>080</NS>
    <M>2</M>
</DT>';
```

and the output should be

```
S   AB    NS   BN
534 2011  238  2
534 2011  239  1
534 2011  240  1
535 2000  135  2
535 2000  140  2
536 NULL  005  2
113 2006  075  2
113 2006  077  2
113 2006  080  2
```

As you see, there is one more column which is not always filled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This XML is somewhat denormalized, as each pair of `NS` and `M` nodes go together.**

Unfortunately, SQL Server does not support `following::` axis, which would have made this much simpler, so we need to hack it with a `>>` (is-following?) predicate.

```sql
SELECT
    X1.DT.value('(S/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') AS S,
    X1.DT.value('(AB/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') AS AB,
    X2.NS.value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') AS NS,
    X2.NS.value('(let $this := . return parent::DT/M[. >> $this]/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') AS M
FROM @xml.nodes('/DT') X1(DT)
CROSS APPLY X1.DT.nodes('NS') AS X2(NS);
```

The way this works is that we first shred the `DT` nodes.

Then we further shred only the `NS` nodes.

Then `M` is calculated like this:

- `(let $this := .` set $this variable to current `NS` node
- `return parent::DT/M` return the first `M` node of the parent of this node, which ...
- `[. >> $this]` ... is positioned after $this

> This assumes there is only one `S` node

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/132724)

Comment: Good answer, +1 from my side!

Comment: Thank you so much! This works with the given example! I will update the question, maybe you can help me again :)

Comment: One more question. The xml file is 60GB and it takes about 16 hours to run your query. Is there something to speed things up?

Comment: I would suggest in that case to use a client app/script to shred the XML and do a bulk insert, perhaps in C# or Powershell. Because of the way that hack works, it is pretty slow because it is reading all previous nodes every time. Also SQL Server needs to load the whole thing into memory (not sure how you are doing that with 60GB) but a client app could stream it from file

Comment: Ok, will try that... P.S. my machine has ~760GB of RAM, maybe thats the realon